# Blame Error during SonarQube Scanner execution

Tags: sonarqube, git-blame

I am using sonarqube-6.0 and i tried with a sample example to run with sonar-scanner

i am getting the blame ERROR when ever I run any project in sonar-scanner

The file Conf in sonar-scanner configuration is vi sonar-scanner.properties

#

```js
# must be unique in a given SonarQube instance
sonar.projectKey=SonarSource-sonar-examples-8051d9d
# this is the name and version displayed in the SonarQube UI. Was mandatory prior to SonarQube 6.1.
sonar.projectName=java-maven-simple
sonar.projectVersion=1.0

# Path is relative to the sonar-project.properties file. Replace "\" by "/" on Windows.
# Since SonarQube 4.2, this property is optional if sonar.modules is set.
# If not set, SonarQube starts looking for source code from the directory containing
# the sonar-project.properties file.
sonar.sources=/Users/kingslee/work/software/projects/sonar-scanner-2.8/bin/sonar-examples

# Encoding of the source code. Default is default system encoding
#sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
~
```

When i run command ./sonar-scanner these are the error which i get frequently

```js
ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to blame file sonar-examples/plugins/java-custom-rules/src/main/java/org/sonar/samples/java/MyJavaFileCheckRegistrar.java
 at org.sonarsource.scm.git.JGitBlameCommand.blame(JGitBlameCommand.java:128)
 at org.sonarsource.scm.git.JGitBlameCommand.access$000(JGitBlameCommand.java:44)
 at org.sonarsource.scm.git.JGitBlameCommand$1.call(JGitBlameCommand.java:112)
 at org.sonarsource.scm.git.JGitBlameCommand$1.call(JGitBlameCommand.java:109)
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at org.eclipse.jgit.internal.storage.file.UnpackedObjectCache$Table.index(UnpackedObjectCache.java:146)
 at org.eclipse.jgit.internal.storage.file.UnpackedObjectCache$Table.contains(UnpackedObjectCache.java:109)
 at org.eclipse.jgit.internal.storage.file.UnpackedObjectCache.isUnpacked(UnpackedObjectCache.java:64)
 at org.eclipse.jgit.internal.storage.file.ObjectDirectory.openObject(ObjectDirectory.java:376)
 at org.eclipse.jgit.internal.storage.file.WindowCursor.open(WindowCursor.java:142)
 at org.eclipse.jgit.lib.ObjectReader.open(ObjectReader.java:226)
 at org.eclipse.jgit.blame.BlameGenerator.push(BlameGenerator.java:317)
 at org.eclipse.jgit.api.BlameCommand.call(BlameCommand.java:216)
 at org.sonarsource.scm.git.JGitBlameCommand.blame(JGitBlameCommand.java:126)
 ... 7 more
ERROR: 
ERROR: Re-run SonarQube Scanner using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
```

Comment: Just a question: why are you storing the sample project in the installation folder of the SonarQube Scanner tool?? ("/Users/kingslee/work/software/projects/sonar-scanner-2.8/bin/sonar-examples")

Comment: @Fabrice-SonarSourceTeam I just kept it ... when i do keep the sample project outside also i do get the same error is there any other possibility to resolve this issue